# ¿Como hacer un leer mas?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un texto que estoy cargando desde la base de datos, pero es muy largo por lo que estaba pensando en hacer un efecto en JavaScript de leer mas, (o menos). Eh buscado informacion al respecto pero lo muestran con dos < div > y no es precisamente lo que necesito. Espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: "no es precisamente lo que necesito" no da muchos detalles, fijate si las respuestas en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/182950/c%C3%B3mo-realizar-el-efecto-de-leer-mas te sirven o si hay mas detalles

Comment: Podrias probar utilizar Shave https://dollarshaveclub.github.io/shave/

Answer (score 2):

Si te sirve, te dejo un ejemplo de cómo podrías lograrlo con Bootstrap (Jquery ya implícito)

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-5" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Leer mas</button>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
</div>
```