# ¿Cómo contar todos los caracteres solicitados fuera o dentro de otras etiquetas html?

Tags: jquery

Tengo problemas con mi código de **Read-More**, si en algunas circunstancias los caracteres mínimos a mostrar se encuentran dentro de una etiqueta, ejemplo;

```
<div class="toggole-text">
    <div>Back to School Week has been a major success in the past. The week has connected thousands of alumni with their old schools so they can inspire current students as career and education role models. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, odio? Consequuntur expedita neque cumque necessitatibus natus, beatae modi. <br><br> Back to School Week has been a major success in the past. The week has connected thousands of alumni with their old schools so they can inspire current students as career and education role models. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, odio? Consequuntur expedita neque cumque necessitatibus natus, beatae modi. </div>
</div>
```

El código jQuery no contabiliza esos caracteres, dando como consecuencia un resultado inesperado, es decir se mostrara todo el contenido del texto de tal forma: https://jsfiddle.net/qe6dyt9n/

> Porque el código jQuery no cuenta los caracteres que están dentro de otras etiquetas html.

Pero si existe algún texto sin estar dentro de otra etiqueta a excepción de el div `<div class="toggle-text"></div>`, el código si funcionara:

```
<div class="toggole-text">
    Back to School Week has been a major success in the past. The week has connected thousands of alumni with their old schools so they can inspire current students as career and education role models. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, odio? Consequuntur expedita neque cumque necessitatibus natus, beatae modi. <br><br> Back to School Week has been a major success in the past. The week has connected thousands of alumni with their old schools so they can inspire current students as career and education role models. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, odio? Consequuntur expedita neque cumque necessitatibus natus, beatae modi. 
</div>
```

Siempre en cuando ese texto pase de los caracteres mínimos `var showChar = 190;`, teniendo como resultado una funcionalidad agradable ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/qe6dyt9n/1/

> Pero no puedo estar consciente de que estas condiciones siempre se cumplirán, en este caso es cierto que el código se funciona, porque es un código que se ha editado a fondo a las expectativas que el código jQuery debe recibir, pero en el caso de que otros los usuarios publiquen algún **post** o un **articulo** a través desde el editor de texto, como el plugin WYSIWYG, ustedes deben saber que estos tipos de editores agregan a todo texto/caracteres o párrafos dentro de una etiqueta de acuerdo con las funcionalidades o estilos/funciones que se agregan al texto desde ese editor.

El código completo o en https://jsfiddle.net/xp64zdom/

```js
$(function() {
  var showChar = 190;  // How many characters are shown by default
  var ellipsestext = "...";
  var moretext = "Read more";
  var lesstext = "Read less";

  //Cut content based on showChar
  if ($(".toggle-text").length) {
   $(".toggle-text").each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();
    console.log(content);

    if(content.length > showChar) {
     var contentExcert = content.substr(0, showChar);
     var contentRest = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);
     var html = contentExcert + '<span class="toggle-text-ellipses">' + ellipsestext + ' </span> <span class="toggle-text-content"><span>' + contentRest + '</span><a href="javascript:;" class="toggle-text-link">' + moretext + '</a></span>';
     $(this).html(html);    
    }
   });
  }

  //Toggle content when click on read more link
  $(".toggle-text-link").click(function() {
   if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
    $(this).removeClass("less");
    $(this).html(moretext);
   } else {
    $(this).addClass("less");
    $(this).html(lesstext);
   }
   $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
   $(this).prev().toggle();
   return false;
  });
 });
```

```css
.toggle-text {
   max-width: 400px;
  }
  .toggle-text-content span {
   display: none;
  }
  .toggle-text-link {
   display: block;
   margin: 20px 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle-text">
 <h4>Descripción</h4>
 <div>
  <p>Back to School Week has been a major success in the past. The week has connected thousands of alumni with their old schools so they can inspire current students as career and education role models. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, odio? Consequuntur expedita neque cumque necessitatibus natus, beatae modi.</p><br>

  <p>
   <ul class="list-style-disc">
    <li>Cuando prepara su café, utiliza lógica.</li>
    <li>Cuando vas a la escuela, utiliza lógica.</li>
    <li>Y hasta para invertir en un curso usted utiliza lógica.</li>
   </ul>
  </p><br>

  <p>Back to School Week has been a major success in the past. The week has connected thousands of alumni with their old schools so they can inspire current students as career and education role models. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, odio? Consequuntur expedita neque cumque necessitatibus natus, beatae modi.</p><br>

  <p>
   <ul class="list-style-disc">
    <li>Usted necesita desarrollar un sitio web, lógica de programación.</li>
    <li>Un software, necesita lógica de programación.</li>
    <li>Un informe sensacional en Excel, lógica de programación.</li>
   </ul>
   Una aplicación móvil para su jefe / cliente de acceso en cualquier momento, desde cualquier lugar... necesita lógica de programación.
  </p><br>

  <p>Back to School Week has been a major success in the past. The week has connected thousands of alumni with their old schools so they can inspire current students as career and education role models. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, odio? Consequuntur expedita neque cumque necessitatibus natus, beatae modi.</p><br>

  <p>Back to School Week has been a major success in the past. The week has connected thousands of alumni with their old schools so they can inspire current students as career and education role models. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, odio? Consequuntur expedita neque cumque necessitatibus natus, beatae modi.</p><br>

  <p>Back to School Week has been a major success in the past. The week has connected thousands of alumni with their old schools so they can inspire current students as career and education role models. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, odio? Consequuntur expedita neque cumque necessitatibus natus, beatae modi.</p><br>

  <p>Back to School Week has been a major success in the past. The week has connected thousands of alumni with their old schools so they can inspire current students as career and education role models. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, odio? Consequuntur expedita neque cumque necessitatibus natus, beatae modi.</p><br>

  <p>Back to School Week has been a major success in the past. The week has connected thousands of alumni with their old schools so they can inspire current students as career and education role models. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, odio? Consequuntur expedita neque cumque necessitatibus natus, beatae modi.</p><br>

  <p>Back to School Week has been a major success in the past. The week has connected thousands of alumni with their old schools so they can inspire current students as career and education role models. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, odio? Consequuntur expedita neque cumque necessitatibus natus, beatae modi.</p><br>
 </div>
 <div class="heading-part">
  <h4>¿Temas de interes?</h4>
   <ul class="list-style-disc">
    <li>Programadores.</li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

La idea de todo este trabajo, es mostrar al lector cierta parte de un texto y, que mediante un enlace **Read-More** desplegar el resto del texto oculto para que el lector continué con toda la lectura, claro también existe la posibilidad de ocultar el texto mediante un enlace **Read-Less**.

Pueden explicarme qué cambios o qué código debo agregar al código jQuery, para que el código contabilice todo los caracteres ya sea que esos caracteres estén solo dentro del div  sin ninguna otra etiqueta y, de igual forma independientemente de si esos caracteres están dentro de otras etiquetas o no contabilizarlos igual para no presentar esos problemas que he detallado.

¿Existe esa posibilidad de contabilizar todos los caracteres que se encuentran dentro del div `<div class="toggle-text"></div>` sin importar de que ese texto se encuentre o no dentro de otras etiquetas `HTML` ya sea `p, div, span, ul, li` u otras?

Comment: Quizás te sirva esto que encontré. https://codepen.io/Idered/pen/AeBgF

Comment: @ArtEze Gracias si lo tengo, pero me llamó más la atención el código de mí pregunta, por sus funcionalidades que tiene :) pero una persona me comentó que esto: `var countnoHTMLtags = OriginalString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");` podría solucionar mi problema, pero no me explico cómo funciona, donde debería agregar o con qué línea reemplazar, usted quizas sabes algo.

Comment: creo que el mayor problema es dónde establecer el corte, si querés contar caracteres [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) te da el texto libre de tags, [`.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) te da el texto visible libre de tags (considera el CSS), si contas los caracteres del html puede haber un `<a href="unadireccionwebmuymuylarga" alt="un texto alternativomuylargo" >el texto realmente visible</a>` que te rompe los cálculos ( insertar un span en el medio de un href puede dar resultados muy graciosos )

Comment: se me viene a la cabeza como un seccionador de web , algo que solo cuente los espacios o caracteres desde el inicio hasta el fin. luego aplique una capa hidden a un texto que sobre pase la cantidad indicada y que con el boton readmore o readless pueda quitar esa propiedad...

Comment: ni idea de como hacerlo pero ya vere si puedo contribuir :D mañana empiezo a ver que sale .

Comment: @aloMalbarez Gracias por el tiempo dedicado chicos, se les agradece un motón, contribuí con un +1  :) saludos ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que al intentar meterlo todo en el mismo bloque el no hace distinción entre las etiquetas que tenga el texto como comentas.

La solución podría estar en dividirlo en dos. Te sobraría con substituir la comprobación y añadirlo en dos partes:

Reemplazar:

```
if(content.length > showChar) {
                    var contentExcert = content.substr(0, showChar);
                    var contentRest = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);
                    var html = contentExcert + '<span class="toggle-text-ellipses">' + ellipsestext + ' </span> <span class="toggle-text-content"><span>' + contentRest + '</span><a href="javascript:;" class="toggle-text-link">' + moretext + '</a></span>';
                    $(this).html(html);             
                }
```

por esto:

```
if(content.length > showChar) {
                    var contentExcert = content.substr(0, showChar);
                    var contentRest = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);
                    var html = contentExcert + '<span class="toggle-text-ellipses">' + ellipsestext + ' </span>'
                    var rest = '<span class="toggle-text-content"><span>' + content + '</span><a href="javascript:;" class="toggle-text-link">' + moretext + '</a></span>';
                    $(this).html(html); 
                    $(this).append(rest);   
                }
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kogLz2x8/1/

Comment: Me agrada su solución, sobre todo porque está basada al código existente, mostrándome ejemplo de que debo reemplazar :) lo reviso más tarde que este en casa :)

Answer (score 2):

Se me ocurre una solución simple, mediante el uso de expresiones regulares podrías tratar todo el contenido para eliminar las etiquetas **HTML** que contenga. De esta manera tendrías tan solo el texto que contiene ese bloque, pudiendo contabilizar de manera eficiente el número de caracteres textuales.

```js
var texto = '<p id="una_id" class="una clase">Elemento con etiquetas <strong>que quiero</strong> que desaparezcan.</p><p class="otras_clase">Y esta es otra frase en otro párrafo diferente</p>';

var sin_tags = texto.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
sin_tags =  sin_tags.replace(/[\n\r]+/g, '');
sin_tags = sin_tags.replace(/\s{2,10}/g, ' ');
sin_tags = $.trim(sin_tags);

console.log('Este es el texto sin etiquetas -> ' + sin_tags);
console.log('Cantidad de caracteres -> ' + sin_tags.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Usando el `div` que pones de ejemplo pero ligeramente alterado para darle más complejidad:

```js
var texto = $('.toggole-text').html();

var sin_tags = texto.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
sin_tags =  sin_tags.replace(/[\n\r]+/g, '');
sin_tags = sin_tags.replace(/\s{2,10}/g, ' ');
sin_tags = $.trim(sin_tags);

console.log('Este es el texto sin etiquetas -> ' + sin_tags);
console.log('Cantidad de caracteres -> ' + sin_tags.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggole-text">
    <p>Back to School Week has been a major success in the past. The week has connected thousands of alumni with their old schools so they can inspire current students as career and education role models. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, odio? Consequuntur expedita neque cumque necessitatibus natus, beatae modi. <br><br> Back to School Week has been a major success in the past. The week has connected thousands of alumni with their old schools so they can inspire current students as career and education role models. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, odio? Consequuntur expedita neque cumque necessitatibus natus, beatae modi.</p>
    <div class="otro_div">
      <p>12345</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Como puedes ver, el contenido pasa por varias expresiones regulares, la primera elimina todas las etiquetas, la segunda los retornos de carro y saltos de línea que quedan debido a la primera y la última es una llamada a la función `trim()`, que elimina los espacios en blanco al principio y al final de la cadena.

De esta manera conseguirías un número bastante exacto de caracteres de texto limpio. No llega a ser exacto de verdad porque entre contenidos de diferentes `divs` nos quedaría un espacio (un caracter de más por cada `div` interno), pero creo que es lo suficientemente preciso como para crear un sistema de **Read more** como el que nos expones.

Comment: Gracias por responder, analizaré la solución que me has proporcionado tarde cuando llegue a casa :)

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) en el elemento padre, y luego reemplazar múltiples espacios, tabs y newlines con un regexp para obtener la cantidad de caracteres.

```js
var str = document.getElementById('eltexto').textContent;
var strLimpio = str.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
console.log(str, strLimpio, strLimpio.length);
```

```html
<div id=eltexto class="toggole-text">
  <div>Back to School Week has been a major success in the past. The week has connected thousands of alumni with their old schools so they can inspire current students as career and education role models. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit. <strong>Quia, odio?</strong> Consequuntur expedita neque cumque necessitatibus natus, beatae modi. <br><br> Back to School Week has been a major success in the past. The week has connected thousands of alumni with their old schools so they can
    inspire current students as career and education role models.
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
      <li>Quia, odio? Consequuntur expedita neque cumque necessitatibus natus, beatae modi.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Un ejemplo práctico utilizando el editor de [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) que muestra la diferencia entre contar los caracteres del html (resumen con formato) y contar los caracteres sin tags (mostrar resumen sin formato) :

En ambos casos se muestran resumen/texto completo como dos divs diferentes, basándose en el estado de un `checkbox` y con dos `labels` para cada uno ( variación de https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/187565/81450 )

```js
// Editor obtenido de
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

addContent = function(html) {
  // creamos un div para contener el html completo
  var fullHtmlDiv = document.createElement("div");
  fullHtmlDiv.classList.add("completo");
  fullHtmlDiv.innerHTML = html;
  // texto sin tags
  let soloTexto = fullHtmlDiv.textContent;
  // limpiar espacios
  var strLimpio = soloTexto.replace(/\s\s+/g, " ");
  // cantidad de caracteres sin contar tags
  var textoLength = strLimpio.length;
  console.log(textoLength);

  var showChar = 190; // How many characters are shown by default
  var ellipsestext = "...";
  var moretext = "Read more";
  var lesstext = "Read less";

  // obtenemos un substring con y sin formato (tags)
  var conFormato = fullHtmlDiv.innerHTML.substring(0, showChar);
  var sinFormato = strLimpio.substring(0, showChar);

  // creamos un fragment para cada resultado
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment
  var fragCF = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var fragSF = document.createDocumentFragment();

  if (showChar < textoLength) {
    // readmore via CSS
    var chkCF = document.createElement("input");
    chkCF.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    chkCF.classList.add("leermasEstado");
    var chkSF = chkCF.cloneNode();

    // asignamos un id para el label
    chkCF.id = "itemCF-" + losTextos.childElementCount + 1;
    chkSF.id = "itemSF-" + losTextosSinFormato.childElementCount + 1;

    // creamos labels para leer mas y leer menos
    var lblCFM = document.createElement("label");
    lblCFM.classList.add("leermasCambia");
    lblCFM.innerHTML = '<span class="no">' + ellipsestext + " " + moretext + "</span>";
    var lblCFL = lblCFM.cloneNode();
    lblCFL.innerHTML = '<span class="si">' + lesstext + "</span>";
    var lblSFM = lblCFM.cloneNode(true);
    var lblSFL = lblCFL.cloneNode(true);

    // cada label con su checkbox id
    lblCFM.setAttribute("for", chkCF.id);
    lblCFL.setAttribute("for", chkCF.id);

    lblSFM.setAttribute("for", chkSF.id);
    lblSFL.setAttribute("for", chkSF.id);

    // añadimos los checkbox que registran el estado de leermas
    fragCF.appendChild(chkCF);
    fragSF.appendChild(chkSF);

    console.log("texto sin formato:", sinFormato);
    console.log("html (texto con formato):", conFormato);

    // añadimos el resumen
    var cFdiv = document.createElement("div");
    cFdiv.innerHTML = conFormato;
    cFdiv.classList.add("resumen");
    console.log("Html normalizado:", cFdiv.innerHTML);
    // label de leer mas
    cFdiv.appendChild(lblCFM);
    fragCF.appendChild(cFdiv);

    var sFdiv = document.createElement("div");
    var txt = document.createTextNode(sinFormato);
    sFdiv.appendChild(txt);
    sFdiv.classList.add("resumen");
    // label de leer mas
    sFdiv.appendChild(lblSFM);
    fragSF.appendChild(sFdiv);

    // añadimos los label de leer menos
    var SFfullHtmlDiv = fullHtmlDiv.cloneNode(true);
    fullHtmlDiv.appendChild(lblCFL);
    SFfullHtmlDiv.appendChild(lblSFL);

    // añadimos el texto completo
    fragCF.appendChild(fullHtmlDiv);
    fragSF.appendChild(SFfullHtmlDiv);
  } else {
    // solo el texto completo
    fragCF.appendChild(fullHtmlDiv);
    fragSF.appendChild(fullHtmlDiv.cloneNode(true));
  }
  // creamos un contenedor para cada fragment
  var cfItem = document.createElement("div");
  cfItem.classList.add("toggleitem");
  var sfItem = cfItem.cloneNode();

  cfItem.appendChild(fragCF);
  sfItem.appendChild(fragSF);

  // añadimos contenedores a cada tipo de resultado
  losTextos.appendChild(cfItem);
  losTextosSinFormato.appendChild(sfItem);
};
```

```css
#elForm,
#losTextos,
#losTextosSinFormato {
  width: 30vw;
  float: left;
}

#textBox {
  max-width: 90%;
}

input.leermasEstado {
  display: none;
}

.leermasCambia span {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

input.leermasEstado:checked~.resumen,
input.leermasEstado:checked~.leermasCambia span.no,
input.leermasEstado:not(:checked)~.completo,
input.leermasEstado:not(:checked)~.leermasCambia span.si {
  display: none;
}

input.leermasEstado:not(:checked)~.resumen,
input.leermasEstado:not(:checked)~.leermasCambia span.no {
  display: block;
}

.toggleitem {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Rich Text Editor</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var oDoc, sDefTxt;

    function initDoc() {
      oDoc = document.getElementById("textBox");
      sDefTxt = oDoc.innerHTML;
      if (document.compForm.switchMode.checked) {
        setDocMode(true);
      }
    }

    function formatDoc(sCmd, sValue) {
      if (validateMode()) {
        document.execCommand(sCmd, false, sValue);
        oDoc.focus();
      }
    }

    function validateMode() {
      if (!document.compForm.switchMode.checked) {
        return true;
      }
      alert("Uncheck \"Show HTML\".");
      oDoc.focus();
      return false;
    }

    function setDocMode(bToSource) {
      var oContent;
      if (bToSource) {
        oContent = document.createTextNode(oDoc.innerHTML);
        oDoc.innerHTML = "";
        var oPre = document.createElement("pre");
        oDoc.contentEditable = false;
        oPre.id = "sourceText";
        oPre.contentEditable = true;
        oPre.appendChild(oContent);
        oDoc.appendChild(oPre);
        document.execCommand("defaultParagraphSeparator", false, "div");
      } else {
        if (document.all) {
          oDoc.innerHTML = oDoc.innerText;
        } else {
          oContent = document.createRange();
          oContent.selectNodeContents(oDoc.firstChild);
          oDoc.innerHTML = oContent.toString();
        }
        oDoc.contentEditable = true;
      }
      oDoc.focus();
    }

    function printDoc() {
      if (!validateMode()) {
        return;
      }
      var oPrntWin = window.open("", "_blank", "width=450,height=470,left=400,top=100,menubar=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes");
      oPrntWin.document.open();
      oPrntWin.document.write("<!doctype html><html><head><title>Print<\/title><\/head><body onload=\"print();\">" + oDoc.innerHTML + "<\/body><\/html>");
      oPrntWin.document.close();
    }
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .intLink {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    img.intLink {
      border: 0;
    }
    
    #toolBar1 select {
      font-size: 10px;
    }
    
    #textBox {
      width: 100%;
      height: 150px;
      border: 1px #000000 solid;
      padding: 12px;
      overflow: scroll;
    }
    
    #textBox #sourceText {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      min-width: 498px;
      min-height: 200px;
    }
    
    #editMode label {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onload="initDoc();">
  <div id=elForm>
    <form name="compForm" onsubmit="if(validateMode()){this.myDoc.value=oDoc.innerHTML;addContent(this.myDoc.value);return false;}return false;">
      <input type="hidden" name="myDoc">
      <div id="toolBar1">
        <select onchange="formatDoc('formatblock',this[this.selectedIndex].value);this.selectedIndex=0;">
          <option selected>- formatting -</option>
          <option value="h1">Title 1 &lt;h1&gt;</option>
          <option value="h2">Title 2 &lt;h2&gt;</option>
          <option value="h3">Title 3 &lt;h3&gt;</option>
          <option value="h4">Title 4 &lt;h4&gt;</option>
          <option value="h5">Title 5 &lt;h5&gt;</option>
          <option value="h6">Subtitle &lt;h6&gt;</option>
          <option value="p">Paragraph &lt;p&gt;</option>
          <option value="pre">Preformatted &lt;pre&gt;</option>
        </select>
        <select onchange="formatDoc('fontname',this[this.selectedIndex].value);this.selectedIndex=0;">
          <option class="heading" selected>- font -</option>
          <option>Arial</option>
          <option>Arial Black</option>
          <option>Courier New</option>
          <option>Times New Roman</option>
        </select>
        <select onchange="formatDoc('fontsize',this[this.selectedIndex].value);this.selectedIndex=0;">
          <option class="heading" selected>- size -</option>
          <option value="1">Very small</option>
          <option value="2">A bit small</option>
          <option value="3">Normal</option>
          <option value="4">Medium-large</option>
          <option value="5">Big</option>
          <option value="6">Very big</option>
          <option value="7">Maximum</option>
        </select>
        <select onchange="formatDoc('forecolor',this[this.selectedIndex].value);this.selectedIndex=0;">
          <option class="heading" selected>- color -</option>
          <option value="red">Red</option>
          <option value="blue">Blue</option>
          <option value="green">Green</option>
          <option value="black">Black</option>
        </select>
        <select onchange="formatDoc('backcolor',this[this.selectedIndex].value);this.selectedIndex=0;">
          <option class="heading" selected>- background -</option>
          <option value="red">Red</option>
          <option value="green">Green</option>
          <option value="black">Black</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div id="toolBar2">
        <img class="intLink" title="Clean" onclick="if(validateMode()&&confirm('Are you sure?')){oDoc.innerHTML=sDefTxt};" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAIQbAD04KTRLYzFRjlldZl9vj1dusY14WYODhpWIbbSVFY6O7IOXw5qbms+wUbCztca0ccS4kdDQjdTLtMrL1O3YitHa7OPcsd/f4PfvrvDv8Pv5xv///////////////////yH5BAEKAB8ALAAAAAAWABYAAAV84CeOZGmeaKqubMteyzK547QoBcFWTm/jgsHq4rhMLoxFIehQQSAWR+Z4IAyaJ0kEgtFoLIzLwRE4oCQWrxoTOTAIhMCZ0tVgMBQKZHAYyFEWEV14eQ8IflhnEHmFDQkAiSkQCI2PDC4QBg+OAJc0ewadNCOgo6anqKkoIQA7"
        />
        <img class="intLink" title="Print" onclick="printDoc();" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
        <img class="intLink" title="Undo" onclick="formatDoc('undo');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAOMKADljwliE33mOrpGjuYKl8aezxqPD+7/I19DV3NHa7P///////////////////////yH5BAEKAA8ALAAAAAAWABYAAARR8MlJq7046807TkaYeJJBnES4EeUJvIGapWYAC0CsocQ7SDlWJkAkCA6ToMYWIARGQF3mRQVIEjkkSVLIbSfEwhdRIH4fh/DZMICe3/C4nBQBADs="
        />
        <img class="intLink" title="Redo" onclick="formatDoc('redo');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAMIHAB1ChDljwl9vj1iE34Kl8aPD+7/I1////yH5BAEKAAcALAAAAAAWABYAAANKeLrc/jDKSesyphi7SiEgsVXZEATDICqBVJjpqWZt9NaEDNbQK1wCQsxlYnxMAImhyDoFAElJasRRvAZVRqqQXUy7Cgx4TC6bswkAOw=="
        />
        <img class="intLink" title="Remove formatting" onclick="formatDoc('removeFormat')" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
        <img class="intLink" title="Bold" onclick="formatDoc('bold');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAWABYAQAInhI+pa+H9mJy0LhdgtrxzDG5WGFVk6aXqyk6Y9kXvKKNuLbb6zgMFADs=" />
        <img class="intLink" title="Italic" onclick="formatDoc('italic');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAKEDAAAAAF9vj5WIbf///yH5BAEAAAMALAAAAAAWABYAAAIjnI+py+0Po5x0gXvruEKHrF2BB1YiCWgbMFIYpsbyTNd2UwAAOw==" />
        <img class="intLink" title="Underline" onclick="formatDoc('underline');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAKECAAAAAF9vj////////yH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAWABYAAAIrlI+py+0Po5zUgAsEzvEeL4Ea15EiJJ5PSqJmuwKBEKgxVuXWtun+DwxCCgA7" />
        <img class="intLink" title="Left align" onclick="formatDoc('justifyleft');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAWABYAQAIghI+py+0Po5y02ouz3jL4D4JMGELkGYxo+qzl4nKyXAAAOw==" />
        <img class="intLink" title="Center align" onclick="formatDoc('justifycenter');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAWABYAQAIfhI+py+0Po5y02ouz3jL4D4JOGI7kaZ5Bqn4sycVbAQA7" />
        <img class="intLink" title="Right align" onclick="formatDoc('justifyright');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAWABYAQAIghI+py+0Po5y02ouz3jL4D4JQGDLkGYxouqzl43JyVgAAOw==" />
        <img class="intLink" title="Numbered list" onclick="formatDoc('insertorderedlist');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAMIGAAAAADljwliE35GjuaezxtHa7P///////yH5BAEAAAcALAAAAAAWABYAAAM2eLrc/jDKSespwjoRFvggCBUBoTFBeq6QIAysQnRHaEOzyaZ07Lu9lUBnC0UGQU1K52s6n5oEADs="
        />
        <img class="intLink" title="Dotted list" onclick="formatDoc('insertunorderedlist');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAMIGAAAAAB1ChF9vj1iE33mOrqezxv///////yH5BAEAAAcALAAAAAAWABYAAAMyeLrc/jDKSesppNhGRlBAKIZRERBbqm6YtnbfMY7lud64UwiuKnigGQliQuWOyKQykgAAOw=="
        />
        <img class="intLink" title="Quote" onclick="formatDoc('formatblock','blockquote');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAIQXAC1NqjFRjkBgmT9nqUJnsk9xrFJ7u2R9qmKBt1iGzHmOrm6Sz4OXw3Odz4Cl2ZSnw6KxyqO306K63bG70bTB0rDI3bvI4P///////////////////////////////////yH5BAEKAB8ALAAAAAAWABYAAAVP4CeOZGmeaKqubEs2CekkErvEI1zZuOgYFlakECEZFi0GgTGKEBATFmJAVXweVOoKEQgABB9IQDCmrLpjETrQQlhHjINrTq/b7/i8fp8PAQA7"
        />
        <img class="intLink" title="Delete indentation" onclick="formatDoc('outdent');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAMIHAAAAADljwliE35GjuaezxtDV3NHa7P///yH5BAEAAAcALAAAAAAWABYAAAM2eLrc/jDKCQG9F2i7u8agQgyK1z2EIBil+TWqEMxhMczsYVJ3e4ahk+sFnAgtxSQDqWw6n5cEADs="
        />
        <img class="intLink" title="Add indentation" onclick="formatDoc('indent');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAOMIAAAAADljwl9vj1iE35GjuaezxtDV3NHa7P///////////////////////////////yH5BAEAAAgALAAAAAAWABYAAAQ7EMlJq704650B/x8gemMpgugwHJNZXodKsO5oqUOgo5KhBwWESyMQsCRDHu9VOyk5TM9zSpFSr9gsJwIAOw=="
        />
        <img class="intLink" title="Hyperlink" onclick="var sLnk=prompt('Write the URL here','http:\/\/');if(sLnk&&sLnk!=''&&sLnk!='http://'){formatDoc('createlink',sLnk)}" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAOMKAB1ChDRLY19vj3mOrpGjuaezxrCztb/I19Ha7Pv8/f///////////////////////yH5BAEKAA8ALAAAAAAWABYAAARY8MlJq7046827/2BYIQVhHg9pEgVGIklyDEUBy/RlE4FQF4dCj2AQXAiJQDCWQCAEBwIioEMQBgSAFhDAGghGi9XgHAhMNoSZgJkJei33UESv2+/4vD4TAQA7"
        />
        <img class="intLink" title="Cut" onclick="formatDoc('cut');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAIQSAB1ChBFNsRJTySJYwjljwkxwl19vj1dusYODhl6MnHmOrpqbmpGjuaezxrCztcDCxL/I18rL1P///////////////////////////////////////////////////////yH5BAEAAB8ALAAAAAAWABYAAAVu4CeOZGmeaKqubDs6TNnEbGNApNG0kbGMi5trwcA9GArXh+FAfBAw5UexUDAQESkRsfhJPwaH4YsEGAAJGisRGAQY7UCC9ZAXBB+74LGCRxIEHwAHdWooDgGJcwpxDisQBQRjIgkDCVlfmZqbmiEAOw=="
        />
        <img class="intLink" title="Copy" onclick="formatDoc('copy');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAIQcAB1ChBFNsTRLYyJYwjljwl9vj1iE31iGzF6MnHWX9HOdz5GjuYCl2YKl8ZOt4qezxqK63aK/9KPD+7DI3b/I17LM/MrL1MLY9NHa7OPs++bx/Pv8/f///////////////yH5BAEAAB8ALAAAAAAWABYAAAWG4CeOZGmeaKqubOum1SQ/kPVOW749BeVSus2CgrCxHptLBbOQxCSNCCaF1GUqwQbBd0JGJAyGJJiobE+LnCaDcXAaEoxhQACgNw0FQx9kP+wmaRgYFBQNeAoGihCAJQsCkJAKOhgXEw8BLQYciooHf5o7EA+kC40qBKkAAAGrpy+wsbKzIiEAOw=="
        />
        <img class="intLink" title="Paste" onclick="formatDoc('paste');" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAWAIQUAD04KTRLY2tXQF9vj414WZWIbXmOrpqbmpGjudClFaezxsa0cb/I1+3YitHa7PrkIPHvbuPs+/fvrvv8/f///////////////////////////////////////////////yH5BAEAAB8ALAAAAAAWABYAAAWN4CeOZGmeaKqubGsusPvBSyFJjVDs6nJLB0khR4AkBCmfsCGBQAoCwjF5gwquVykSFbwZE+AwIBV0GhFog2EwIDchjwRiQo9E2Fx4XD5R+B0DDAEnBXBhBhN2DgwDAQFjJYVhCQYRfgoIDGiQJAWTCQMRiwwMfgicnVcAAAMOaK+bLAOrtLUyt7i5uiUhADs="
        />
      </div>
      <div id="textBox" contenteditable="true">

        <p>Back to School:</p>
        <ol>
          <li>Back to School <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)#Abstract_syntax_tree_interpreters">Week has been a major success</a> in the past.</li>
          <li>The week has connected thousands of alumni with their old schools so they can inspire current students as career and education role models.</li>
          <li>&nbsp;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
        </ol>
        <p><strong>Quia, odio?</strong> Consequuntur expedita neque cumque necessitatibus natus, beatae modi. <br><br> Back to School Week has been a major success in the past. The week has connected thousands of alumni with their old schools so they can
          inspire current students as career and education role models.
        </p>
        <ul>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
          <li>Quia, odio? Consequuntur expedita neque cumque necessitatibus natus, beatae modi.</li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <p id="editMode"><input type="checkbox" name="switchMode" id="switchBox" onchange="setDocMode(this.checked);" /> <label for="switchBox">Show HTML</label></p>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Send" /></p>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id=losTextos>
    <h2>con formato</h2>
  </div>
  <div id=losTextosSinFormato>
    <h2>sin formato</h2>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

En vez de contarlos, la pregunta que yo veo es la siguiente: ¿Cómo limitar un **contenido *HTML*** a una determinada cantidad de caracteres de **texto plano**? La solución es mirar caracter por caracter y ver si cumplen las condiciones para ser contado como texto plano.

La estructura *HTML* de un texto de ejemplo es la siguiente:

```
<div class="texto">
    <div class="ocultado" >
        Ejemplo
    </div>
</div>
```

- Clase `texto`

  - Clase `ocultado`
  - Clase `mostrado` (esta clase se genera mediante *jQuery*)

Lo que hace el *jQuery* es agarrar el texto ocultado, cortarlo y mostrar la parte cortada. Cuando se hace click en **Leer más**, muestra el texto completo agregando la clase `mostrado` al `texto`, que lo extrae desde la clase `ocultado`, que es uno de los hijos del padre del botón **Leer más** o **Leer menos**. Al clickear en **Leer menos**, corta nuevamente el texto, extrayendo desde `ocultado`.

Entonces queda generado mediante *jQuery* de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="texto">
    <div class="ocultado" >
        Ejemplo
    </div>
    <div class="mostrado" >
        Ejem
    </div>
    <a href="#" >Leer más</a>
</div>
```

Al iniciar la página, es automático el proceso de agregar el texto mostrado a partir del oculto, y agregar el enlace que simula ser un botón mediante un `preventDefault` en el `onclick`.

Clickear en el enlace, lo que hará es buscar al padre, mediante `$(this).parent()`, luego se busca el texto ocultado mediante `padre.find(".ocultado").html()` y si es necesario cortarlo, llama a una función propia que va agregando caracteres uno por uno hasta que la cantidad de **caracteres planos** es la cantidad solicitada, que en mi caso es `var cantidad_caracteres = 10`.

Las condiciones para que un caracter sea plano son las siguientes:

- No es el principio de la línea, es decir, que no se cuentan espacios, tabuladores, o saltos de línea (`\x20`, `\x09` o `\x0A` respectivamente) si es el principio de línea. Un principio de línea empieza con un salto de línea.
- Si el último caracter agregado es espacio (`\x20`, `\x09` o `\x0A`), el siguiente espacio se considera duplicado y entonces no es plano (es decir, plano son los contados). Los duplicados, lógicamente solo se pueden contar luego de haber agregado el primer caracter.
- Si el caracter es especial, no es plano. Con especial me refiero al signo de cierre de etiqueta, el signo mayor (`>`).
- Las aperturas (`<`) y los cierres (`>`) de una etiqueta tienen que estar balanceados. Para esto se usa un contador, `var balance = 0`, al encontrar una apertura, suma en 1, al encontrar un cierre, resta 1, es decir, incrementa y decrementa. Al estar el balance en *0*, puede contarlo como plano.

Código completo:

```js
$(function() {
 
 var cantidad_caracteres = 10
 
 function cortar(html_string,cantidad){
  var cortado = []
  var puede_agregar
  var es_espacio = x =>
   x=="\x20"
   || x=="\x0A"
   || x=="\x09"
  ;
  var es_principio = true
  var es_especial = false
  var es_espacio_duplicado = false
  var balance = 0
  var j = 0
  for(var i in html_string){
   var caracter = html_string[i]
   es_especial = false
   if(j>=cantidad){break}
   if(caracter=="\x0A"){
    es_principio = true
   }else{
    if(es_principio){
     es_principio = caracter=="\x20"
     || caracter=="\x09"
    }
   }
   if(caracter=="<"){
    ++balance
   }
   if(caracter==">"){
    --balance
    es_especial = true
   }
   if(cortado.length>0){
    es_espacio_duplicado = (
     es_espacio(caracter)
     && es_espacio(cortado.slice(-1)[0])
    )
   }
   puede_contar = (
    es_principio==false
    && es_especial==false
    && es_espacio_duplicado==false
    && balance<=0
   )
   if(puede_contar){
    ++j
   }
   cortado.push(html_string[i])
  }
  return cortado.join("")
 }
 function agregar_texto(texto){
  var html_string = $(texto).find(".ocultado").html()
  var cortado = cortar(html_string,cantidad_caracteres)
  return $("<div></div>")
   .addClass("mostrado")
   .html(cortado)
  [0];
 }
 function agregar_boton(){
  var textos = ["Leer menos","Leer más"]
  return $("<a>")
   .text(textos[1])
   .attr('href',"#")
   .click(function(x){
    x.preventDefault()
    var padre = $(this).parent()
    var completo = padre.find(".ocultado").html()
    var texto = $(this).text()
    if(texto==textos[0]){
     $(this).text(textos[1])
     var cortado = cortar(completo,cantidad_caracteres)
     padre.find(".mostrado").html(cortado)
    }else{
     $(this).text(textos[0])
     padre.find(".mostrado").html(completo)
    }
   })
  [0];
 }
 var textos = $(".texto")
 textos.map(x=>{
  var texto = textos[x]
  texto.append(agregar_texto(texto))
  texto.append(agregar_boton())
 });
})
```

```css
.texto {
 max-width: 100px;
 margin: 20px 20px;
}

.ocultado {
 display: none;
}

.mostrado {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="textos">
 <div class="texto">
  <div class="ocultado" >
   Est<a style="color:#f00e">e</a> es<b> un texto de prueba.</b>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="texto">
  <div class="ocultado" >
   Este 
   <i>es </i>
   o<b>tro texto de prueba.</b>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```