# Botón spoiler en web

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, web

tengo un código que está diseñado para crear un botón que al darle click se muestre la información/texto que anteriormente le había asignado.

He aquí el código:

```html
<div id="spoiler" style="display: none;">
Aquí escribe lo que no quieras que se lea hasta que den al botón
</div>
<button onclick="if(document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('spoiler') .style.display='none'}" title="Click to show/hide" type="button" class="btn">Ver información </button>
```

El problema es que al añadirlo al código html de mi WordPress no me sale. Simplemente se reemplaza por este otro código:

```html
<div id="spoiler" style="display: none;">Aquí escribe lo que no quieras que se lea hasta que den al botón</div>
<button class="btn" title="Click to show/hide" type="button">Ver información </button>
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Tienes que poner el código en el `onclick`? ¿Puedes ponerlo en un script por separado (y luego asociarlo por separado)?

Comment: Gracias por señalarlo. Pero... ¿cómo hago eso?

Answer (score 3):

Si WordPress quita el atributo `onClick`, una cosa que puedes hacer en ese caso es mover el controlador del evento `click` fuera usando [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) por ejemplo. Algo como esto:

```js
document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (document.getElementById('spoiler').style.display == 'none') {
    document.getElementById('spoiler').style.display = ''
  } else {
    document.getElementById('spoiler').style.display = 'none'
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="spoiler" style="display: none;">
  Aquí escribe lo que no quieras que se lea hasta que den al botón
</div>
<button title="Click to show/hide" type="button" class="btn">Ver información </button>
```

Yo he usado la clase `btn`, pero esa puede ser demasiado genérica, deberías añadir una clase más específica (o un id) al botón para que el controlador de evento sólo se asocie a él y no a otros elementos.

Answer (score 1):

Variación de https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/187565/81450
Sólo CSS + HTML.

```html
<style>
  .btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #ccf;
  }
  /* el spoiler comienza oculto */
  .complete {
    display: none;
  }
  /* el checkbox también oculto */
  input.showmore {
    display: none;
  }
  /* si el checkbox está checked mostrar spoiler */
  input.showmore:checked+.complete {
    display: block;
  }
  /* si el checkbox está checked ocultar label botón */
  input.showmore:checked~label.btn {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
<input type=checkbox id=vermas class=showmore />
<div class=complete>Aquí escribe lo que no quieras que se lea hasta que den al botón</div>
<label for=vermas class="btn" title="Click to show/hide">Ver información</label>
```