# Mostrar u ocultar div con PHP

Tags: javascript, html, php7

Lo que quiero realizar es mostrar un input que esta oculto una vez tickeado el check, ya lo logre con javascript con el siguiente código

```js
function mostrarInput() {
  elemento = document.getElementById("content");
  check = document.getElementById("check");
  
  if (check.checked) {
    elemento.style.display='block';
  }
  else {
    elemento.style.display='none';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="check" name="check" onchange="javascript:mostrarInput()" />
  <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6" id="content" style="display: none;">
  <input class="form-control" value="Contenido">
</div>
```

Ahora quiero realizar la misma acción pero solo con PHP si es posible, ya que no se si es o no posible.

Comment: Poder se puede, pero habra que refrescar la pagina

Comment: Si lo quieres hacer con PHP no te queda otra que pasar por el servidor o usar AJAX y usar js.

Comment: PHP es un lenguaje de programación backend, eso significa que funciona de lado del servidor, necesitas usar AJAX

Comment: Se puede hacer una combinación de ambos lenguajes solo que tendrás que usar una cookie que su tiempo seria modificado cada vez que hagas click en el checkbox

Comment: Aunque en este caso solo seria utilizar javascript por que php solo trabaja de lado del servidor y javascript de lado del cliente.

Comment: tendrias que hacer un echo de https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/243322/81450 ó https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/187565/81450

Answer (score 2, accepted):

con un echo y el javascript entre los tags `<script>`/`</script>` debería funcionar, si el chekbox está en el mismo level del div a mostrar, ver las soluciones html+css en los comentarios

```
<?php 
  // empieza captura de salida
  ob_start();
?>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="check"
     name="check" onchange="javascript:mostrarInput()" />
  <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck"></label>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6" id="content" style="display: none;">
  <input class="form-control" value="Contenido">
</div>
<script>
function mostrarInput() {
  elemento = document.getElementById("content");
  check = document.getElementById("check");

  if (check.checked) {
    elemento.style.display='block';
  }
  else {
    elemento.style.display='none';
  }
}
</script>
<?php // finalizar captura asignarlo a un var
$output = ob_get_clean();

// si convence y no hace falta mas movida, darle al echo

echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

Os he dado una respuesta con código sólo PHP, de hecho he probado lo que el muchacho dice añadiéndole un "submit" el "event check" y sin hacerlo y ambas funcionan, gracias pero me quedo el código, incluso con java a veces tenéis problemas, por no hablar que hay redes mucho mejores para hacer preguntas sobre php, ya que solo permite publicar en CSS/HTML/JavaScript.

Por si acaso alguien no entendió mi respuesta, ¿Cuál es la visibilidad de un objeto HTML que no ha sido escrito en la página web?

P.D.: Esto es un modelo responsive...

Comment: Esto es una respuesta o un comentario?, si es lo último no debe ir aqui donde solo se esperan posibles soluciones al problema expuesto

Comment: Se trata de responder lo mismo con otras palabras ¿lo entendiste?, ¿sabes lo que es la programación PHP responsive?, hay muchos CMS actuales empleándola

Comment: Te hago el comentario por que la redacción no es clara, por otro lado si es complemento de tu anterior respuesta sería mejor que la dejes como edición de tu primer respuesta, conozco de *responsive design* con CSS (via media queries) pero ni idea de que sea programación responsive en PHP

Answer (score 0):

También puedes usar el clásico `summary`/`details`, el resto puede estilizarse con css

```html
<details>
  <summary>Mostrar formulario</summary>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6" id="content">
    <input class="form-control" value="Contenido">
  </div>
</details>
```

Answer (score -1):

que pasaría si cargase en una función de php el código html concreto del elemento o bloque que quiero mostrar, y que testea una variable para ejecutarse o no ejecutarse, y hago que el controlador para mostrarlos y ocultarlos fuese por ejemplo el botón submit de un formulario que además oculta un campo cuyo valor de nombre es la variable que testeo en esa misma función resolviendo siempre el formulario sobre mi propio archivo...

Seria meter el input que deseas mostrar u ocultar en ese contenido de la cabecera que testea si la variable que buscas incluso tiene el dominio que buscas para mostrar el input que te guardas o muestras

p.d.: te recomiendo usar post

Comment: Hola, Kevin. Te invito a consultar [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que tu respuesta sea bien recibida por la comunidad.