# Necesito poner una función en mas de un botón!

Tags: javascript, funciones

Tengo un problema y es que necesito hacer una función para varios botones **("leer mas", "leer menos")** y no tengo idea como hacerlo. Entiendo como hacer la función y llamarla con un solo botón,pero al momento de aplicársela a todos los botones se me complico. Ojalá me puedan dar una mano,saludos!

Comment: Hola, puedes revisar [¿Cómo realizar el efecto de leer mas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/182950/c%c3%b3mo-realizar-el-efecto-de-leer-mas)

Answer (score 0):

Considera y modifica el siguiente ejemplo

```js
$('.open-bio').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('href');

    if ($(id).is(":visible")) {
        $(this).text("Leer mas");
    } else {
        $(this).text("contraer");
    }

    $(id).slideToggle(250);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Texto muy largo<br />
<p>ejemplo</p><br />
<div id="bio1" class="additional" style="display:none">
   descricion 
</div>
<a href="#bio1" class="open-bio">continuar leyendo</a>
<br /><br />

segundo togle<br />
<p>erase una vez</p><br />
<div id="bio2" class="additional" style="display:none">
   si desea leer mas
</div>
<a href="#bio2" class="open-bio">compre su suscripcion en</a>
```

Comment: Hola Miguel, la verdad recién empiezo con esto y no tengo mucha idea, y menos de jquery que creo entender es de ahí el código que me pasaste,lo que estoy aprendiendo ahora es javascript,igual valoro tu tiempo y te agradezco la ayuda,saludo!