# Ponerle una función a mas de un botón en javascript

Tags: javascript

Lo que necesito es que una función me sirva para mas de un botón,por que cuando apretó el "segundo" botón se ejecuta la función del botón "uno",ojala me puedan ayudar.saludos!

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta.  Quizas si pusieras codigo seria mejor.

Comment: Habría que ver el código, pero imagino que debe tener un problema muy trivial.

Comment: asigna el evento a una clase de modo que todo botón que tenga esa clase ejecute tu función

Comment: puede ser que hayas preguntado lo mismo hoy mismo https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/289366/necesito-poner-una-funci%c3%b3n-en-mas-de-un-bot%c3%b3n ? Tienes que agregar mas informacion sino es dificil ayudar. mira esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Podrías utilizar el evento `onClick` en cada botón, y en JavaScript hacer uso de ese evento.
Este sería el código de HTML

```
<input type="Button" onClick="myFunc()" value="Primero"></br> <!--myFunc sería el nombre de tu función-->
<input type="Button" onClick="myFunc()" value="Segundo"></br>
```

Y este sería el de JavaScript

```
function myFunc(){
    //Aquí el código de la función.
    console.log("Has presionado un botón");
    }
```

Recuerda enlazar el archivo de JavaScript mediante

```
    <script src="archivoJS.js"></script>
```

en el archivo de HTML.

Comment: Carlos, es excelente que quieras ayudar, pero la idea es no dar respuestas a preguntas que no cumplan con las reglas de la comunidad. [Pásate por acá](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), para que te contextualices con lo que te comento. Trata de leer hasta el final, en el apartado **Contesta preguntas bien formadas** vas a encontrar esta información.

Comment: No tenía idea de esto, DjCrazy, gracias por comentármelo.

Comment: function mas(){

var x = document.getElementById("parrafo");

if(x.style.display === "none"){
    x.style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("leer").innerHTML = "Leer menos...";

}else {x.style.display = "none"

document.getElementById("leer").innerHTML = "Leer más...";}


}  ese seria el javascript!

Comment: Ivan, edita tu pregunta para agregar el código, evita ponerlo como un comentario. Por favor haz el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que aprendas como funciona la comunidad y de paso ganas reputación.