# ¿Cómo ocultar un link después de un click con CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

Como dice el título quiero ocultar un **link** luego de hacer click sobre el.

Con lo siguiente:

```
.link:hover > a {
    display:inline;
}

.link:active > a{
    display:none;
}
```

Y el link que quiero ocultar lo tengo definido así

```
<div class="link">
    <a onclick="mostrar('div')"></a>
</div>
```

Con esto consigo ocultar el **link**, pero no me ejecuta la función del evento `onClick`. Y si dentro de la función lo intento ocultar, luego cuando paso el mouse sobre el **link** no me lo muestra porque queda con la propiedad definida por `javascript`

¿Estoy haciendo algo mal?

(Si solo espero que el mouse se vaya del elemento, en un celular, se ve feo, porque lo que se muestra tapa el contenido)

Comment: que tipo de contenido estarías mostrando? si es sólo hacer visible un div podés jugar con un radio button/checkbox, un label y selectores hermanos https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/187565/81450

Comment: dentro de la función, además de mostrar el div, se envían datos al servidor, por lo que es necesario que se ejecute la función que muestra el div.

Comment: el display none saca el link del dom, una opción es ocultarlo dentro de la función ( y volverlo a mostrar si falla al ejax por ejemplo )

Answer (score 1):

Lo que deseas es extraño y creo que si se viera tu implementación real se podría buscar soluciones alternativas pero siguiendo las pautas que has puesto en tu pregunta se me ocurre una solución alternativa.

La función `mostrar` no se ejecuta porque para que el evento `click` se dispare, necesitas hacer `mousedown` y `mouseup` sobre el elemento y en el momento en que haces `mouseup` el mismo está oculto, provocando que el evento `click` no se dispare.

Una solución alternativa es simular un evento de `click`: Si capturas las coordenadas del mouse en el momento que haces `mousedown` en el elemento, podrías chequear si al hacer `mouseup` en el documento (o en un elemento padre que no esté oculto) las coordenadas de este último evento están cerca de las coordenadas de origen, en caso de que lo estén sabes que se trata de un `click`, ejecutas la acción que deseas y *reseteas* las variables guardadas para evitar que el evento se lance múltiples veces. Observa el siguiente snippet:

> He añadido los eventos usando `addEventListener` en vez de usar los atributos `HTML` porque siempre prefiero tener estos códigos separados, pero si prefieres usar los atributos solo tienes que adaptar el código:

```js
var a = document.querySelector('.link a');

var limite = 10;
var mouseX;
var mouseY;

// Al presionar en el enlace declaro las variables mouseX y mouseY
a.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
  mouseX = e.pageX;
  mouseY = e.pageY;
});

// Cuando se suelte el mouse en el documento
// Chequear si las variables mouseX y mouseY existen
// y chequear si son cercanas a las coordenadas del nuevo evento
// En caso positivo ejecutar la función
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
  if (
    mouseX &&
    mouseY &&
    Math.abs(e.pageX - mouseX) < limite &&
    Math.abs(e.pageY - mouseY) < limite
  ) {
    console.log("ejecutar mostrar");
  }
  // Resetear las variables
  mouseX = null;
  mouseY = null;
});
```

```css
.link:hover > a {
  display: inline;
}

.link:active > a {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="link">
  <a>enlace</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe la pseudo clase [:visited](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:visited), pero solo se pueden cambiar algunos atributos, `display` no es uno de ellos, pero si `color`:

```css
a:visited {
  color: white;/* <-- El color del background */
}
```

```html
<a href="#">link</a>
```

Una vez que hagamos click, siempre va a aplicar `:visited`.

Comment: no me sirve porque el fondo no es blanco, además necesito que realmente no se vea, porque forma parte de un menú que cuando se pasa por arriba se despliega y cuando se hace click debería desaparecer

Comment: Una cosa es que no se vea, y otra es que desaparezca. Para que no se vea realmente (pero sigue existiendo y ocupando lugar) deberías poner el mismo color que tiene tu fondo, en este caso específico es blanco. No creo que se pueda hacer un display none con una pseudoclase quiza se pueda hacer algo con una transition.

Answer (score 0):

Al llamar la función podés indicarle quién fue el que la llamó y sólo si el proceso tuvo éxito ocultar el enviador y mostrar el div.
Por ejemplo:

```js
var mostrar = function(elemento, enviador) {
  var contenedor = document.querySelector('body');
  contenedor.classList.add('cargando');
  fetch('https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=2&start-with-lorem=1')
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.text();
    })
    .then(function(body) {
      var eldiv = document.querySelector(elemento);
      eldiv.innerHTML = body;
      contenedor.classList.remove('cargando');
      enviador.style.display = 'none';
      eldiv.style.display = 'block';
    });
};
```

```css
.cargando {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22 class%3D%22lds-dual-ring%22 preserveAspectRatio%3D%22xMidYMid%22 style%3D%22background%3A0 0%22 viewBox%3D%220 0 100 100%22%3E%3Ccircle cx%3D%2250%22 cy%3D%2250%22 r%3D%2240%22 fill%3D%22none%22 stroke%3D%22%230DD%22 stroke-dasharray%3D%2262.832 62.832%22 stroke-linecap%3D%22round%22 stroke-width%3D%224%22 transform%3D%22rotate%28126 50 50%29%22%3E%3CanimateTransform attributeName%3D%22transform%22 begin%3D%220s%22 calcMode%3D%22linear%22 dur%3D%221s%22 keyTimes%3D%220%3B1%22 repeatCount%3D%22indefinite%22 type%3D%22rotate%22 values%3D%220 50 50%3B360 50 50%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fcircle%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E') !important;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 10%;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#eldiv {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="link">
  <a onclick="mostrar('#eldiv', this)">mostrar</a>
</div>
<div id=eldiv></div>
```