# JS mostrar/ocultar div: dos clicks

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo este pequeño código en JS que muestra u oculta un div. Lo uso en tres secciones y en las tres sucede lo mismo: debo hacer dos clicks para que se muestren los detalles por primera vez. A partir de ahí funciona bien con un solo click tanto para mostrar como para ocultar

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/base.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/presupuestos_ficha.css" />
        <title>Título de la pagina</title>
        <script>
            function ver_detalles(seccion) {
                if (document.getElementById(seccion).style.display === "none") {
                    document.getElementById("btn_"+seccion).innerHTML = "ocultar detalle";
                    document.getElementById(seccion).style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById(seccion).style.visibility = "visible";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("btn_"+seccion).innerHTML = "mostrar detalle";
                    document.getElementById(seccion).style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById(seccion).style.visibility = "hidden";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4>Desglose de gastos - <span id="btn_detalle_gastos" onclick="ver_detalles('detalle_gastos')">mostrar detalle</span></h4>
        <div id="detalle_gastos"> <!-- este div se carga oculto y se muestra/oculta con la llamada a la función -->
            <div>item 1: $ 32.90</div>
            <div>item 2: $ 72000.00</div>
            <div>item 3: $ 6950.00</div>
            <div>item 4: $ 768.00</div>
            <div>item 5: $ 500.00</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

He probado la función ubicándola en diferentes lugares de la página y siempre sucede lo mismo.

Comment: @padaleiana, acabo de añadir el código resultante donde se puede apreciar el "error".

Comment: Moví tu código al snippet. Como te fijarás, ahora se puede ejecutar el código en la pregunta como para visualizar el comportamiento.

Comment: No está demás decir que [se desaconseja el uso de los eventos inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these): mejor usar los eventos de JS.

Comment: Otro detalle: en el snippet el comportamiento es que "de una" se muestra el detalle (siendo que el texto dice "mostrar detalle", es decir que no debería mostrarse aún el detalle). ¿Esto sucede solo en el snippet o efectivamente es el comportamiento que estás teniendo?

Comment: El comportamiento debe ser: al cargar la pagina, el detalle aparece oculto y el texto debe decir "mostrar detalle". Al hacer click en "mostrar detalle", el detalle se muestra y el texto cambia a "ocultar detalle". Y viceversa. Eso funciona correctamente salvo por la necesidad de los "dos clicks" (o el doble click pero selecciona el texto), que es el comportamiento a corregir.

Comment: Aquí falta saber qué tiene el CSS para que te respondan teniendo en cuenta los estilos que puedas o no estar aplicando. Puede que el JS esté bien pero estés modificando la visibilidad en los estilos

Comment: [Una alternativa sólo HTML+CSS usando checkbox y selectores hermanos.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/187565/81450)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este es el código que terminé usando:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/base.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/presupuestos_ficha.css" />
        <title>Título Pagina</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4>Desglose de gastos - <span id="btn_detalle_gastos" onclick="ver_detalles('detalle_gastos')">mostrar detalle</span></h4>

        <div id="detalle_gastos" class="oculto">
            <div>item 1: $ 32.90</div>
            <div>item 2: $ 72000.00</div>
            <div>item 3: $ 6950.00</div>
            <div>item 4: $ 768.00</div>
            <div>item 5: $ 500.00</div>
        </div>

        <script>
            function ver_detalles(seccion) {

                if (document.getElementById(seccion).classList.contains('oculto')) {
                    document.getElementById("btn_"+seccion).innerHTML = "ocultar detalle";
                    document.getElementById(seccion).classList.replace("oculto", "mostrado");

                } else {
                    document.getElementById("btn_"+seccion).innerHTML = "mostrar detalle";
                    document.getElementById(seccion).classList.replace("mostrado", "oculto");
                }
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Me sirvieron todas las respuestas y adaptaré el código según lo sugerido respecto de los eventos inline.

Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Bien, teniendo en cuenta lo mencionado en este comentario:

> El comportamiento debe ser: al cargar la página, el detalle debe aparecer oculto y el texto debe decir "mostrar detalle". Al hacer click en "mostrar detalle", el detalle se muestra y el texto cambia a "ocultar detalle". Y viceversa.

Una alternativa de solución podría ser crear dos clases que sirvan de "bandera" para mostrar u ocultar el detalle según sea el caso.

Aquí, llamé a las clases *oculto* y *mostrado*.

Dado que [se desaconseja el uso de los eventos inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these), se movió la llamada a la función al evento [click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event), cuyo manejador se agrega en el evento [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event).

Asimismo, el `if` de la función *ver_detalles* busca si el elemento contiene la clase *oculto*. En caso afirmativo, reemplaza esta clase por *mostrado*. En el `else`, viceversa. Se utilizó el método disponible para [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList): [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/replace), y para buscar la clase, el método [contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains).

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (evento) => {
    document.getElementById('btn_detalle_gastos').addEventListener('click', (evento) => {
        ver_detalles('detalle_gastos');
    });
});

function ver_detalles(seccion) {

    if (document.getElementById(seccion).classList.contains('oculto')) {
        document.getElementById("btn_"+seccion).innerHTML = "ocultar detalle";
        document.getElementById(seccion).classList.replace("oculto", "mostrado");

    } else {
        document.getElementById("btn_"+seccion).innerHTML = "mostrar detalle";
        document.getElementById(seccion).classList.replace("mostrado", "oculto");
    }
}
```

```css
.oculto {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.mostrado {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
        <title>Título de la pagina</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4>Desglose de gastos - <span id="btn_detalle_gastos">mostrar detalle</span></h4>
        <div id="detalle_gastos" class="oculto">
            <div>item 1: $ 32.90</div>
            <div>item 2: $ 72000.00</div>
            <div>item 3: $ 6950.00</div>
            <div>item 4: $ 768.00</div>
            <div>item 5: $ 500.00</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Testeado en Firefox v104.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el evento `ondblclick`, en donde este evento ocurre cuando se presiona 2 veces en el elemento:

En tu html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/base.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/presupuestos_ficha.css" />
        <title>Título de la pagina</title>
        <script>
            function ver_detalles(seccion) {
                if (document.getElementById(seccion).style.display === "none") {
                    document.getElementById("btn_"+seccion).innerHTML = "ocultar detalle";
                    document.getElementById(seccion).style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById(seccion).style.visibility = "visible";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("btn_"+seccion).innerHTML = "mostrar detalle";
                    document.getElementById(seccion).style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById(seccion).style.visibility = "hidden";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4>Desglose de gastos - <span id="btn_detalle_gastos" ondblclick="ver_detalles('detalle_gastos')">mostrar detalle</span></h4>
        <div id="detalle_gastos"> <!-- este div se carga oculto y se muestra/oculta con la llamada a la función -->
            <div>item 1: $ 32.90</div>
            <div>item 2: $ 72000.00</div>
            <div>item 3: $ 6950.00</div>
            <div>item 4: $ 768.00</div>
            <div>item 5: $ 500.00</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: OP menciona que el comportamiento inesperado es que la primera vez debe hacer dos clics (no doble clic) para mostrar el detalle, no que desea que se muestre el detalle con doble clic.

Comment: Lo que el autor desea es hacer dos clicks.

Comment: No... Leelo de nuevo :)

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que "dos clicks" y "[doble click](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondblclick.asp)" son distintos?

Comment: No necesariamente (aunque sí son distintos); me refiero a que OP describe que su problema es que debe hacer dos clics, la primera vez, para mostrar el detalle, no a que es su objetivo hacer dos clics para mostrar el detalle. Por eso luego dice "A partir de ahí funciona bien con un solo click tanto para mostrar como para ocultar".

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda. Exacto. Como dice @padaleiana. Quiero hacer un solo click (mas allá de si dos clicks o doble click son diferentes).

Comment: Bueno, eso es lo que yo entendí (Referente al título de tu pregunta). Sería que aclares mejor lo que necesitas, porque en sí se entiende por ambos lados. Tienes muchas soluciones, a mi opinión. más voy por la de @Antonio Galicia, ya que al ejecutar el html ya se visualiza los elementos (sin estar presionándolo al inicio para mostrar), y si quieres integrar el doble click (por lo que entendí, espero no confundirme), puedes usar el evento que te sugiero. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo anulando llamar la función desde el botón, la mejor manera es escuchando el evento y para evitar conflictos agrego el evento  después de terminar de cargar el DOM, con esto puedes poner el **script** al principio o final de tu pagina.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
  var btn = document.getElementById('btn_detalle_gastos');
  var detalle = document.getElementById('detalle_gastos');
  //INICIALIZAMOS EL DIV DETALLE OCULTO
  detalle.style.display = "none";
  
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (detalle.style.display === "none") {
      btn.textContent = "Ocultar detalle";
      detalle.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      btn.textContent = "Mostrar detalle";
      detalle.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <title>Título de la pagina</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h4>Desglose de gastos - <span id="btn_detalle_gastos">Mostrar detalle</span></h4>
  <div id="detalle_gastos">
    <!-- este div se carga oculto y se muestra/oculta con la llamada a la función -->
    <div>item 1: $ 32.90</div>
    <div>item 2: $ 72000.00</div>
    <div>item 3: $ 6950.00</div>
    <div>item 4: $ 768.00</div>
    <div>item 5: $ 500.00</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Dime si te sirvió.

Comment: El DIV con el detalle se carga oculto mediante CSS y el texto "mostrar detalle" es correcto. El cambio se hace correctamente. El problema es que debo dar 2 (dos) clicks la primera vez para que el comportamiento sea el esperado, lo que es incorrecto porque al dar el primer click debería mostrarse el DIV oculto y eso no sucede.

Comment: Lo que OP quería decir, en pocas palabras, es que inicialmente el detalle debe estar oculto (por eso menciona que con dos clics recién se da el comportamiento esperado).

Comment: Lo reviso y modifico mi respuesta.

Comment: Modifique mi respuesta, ahora con el **div** oculto en principio, es eso?

Comment: Según se entiende leyendo su pregunta, sí :)

Comment: El `div`se carga oculto naturalmente. Sucede lo mismo que con el snippet de @padaleiana: ejecutado acá funciona. Las pruebas las hago con Firefox 91.11 y son Opera 63. Además es un código muy básico. El código fuente es ese mismo, cambié los nombres de las opciones a `Item # ` no mas.

Comment: Finalmente lo resolví tanto para mi código como para los propuestos. El CSS que se aplica es `display: none;`y `visibility: hidden;` y en cuanto a JS, estableciendo dichas propiedades de estilo en la carga de la pagina.

Comment: @julio ¡Entonces escríbelo como respuesta, y acéptala! O acepta la respuesta que te haya sido más útil. Recuerda que los comentarios son efímeros, y _no nos llega una notificación_ cuando haces un comentario en alguna de las respuestas.